# Lost modified /etc/hosts file on Amazon EC2 every reboot instance?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, cloud

I have setup an Ubuntu 8.10 server instance on Amazon EC2. I install ejabberd on server, but I face some problems on ejabberd node can't start because hostname on cloud changes each time we relaunch the instance. After I follow this link http://blog.kenweiner.com/2008/05/ejabberd-on-amazon-ec2-ubuntu-ami.html to edit and add hostname in /etc/hosts file, it works. Unfortunately, every time I reboot the server, the /etc/hosts file get reset to default.

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu (desktop) 10.10 on my laptop and the problem with the /etc/hosts files persists. It's reseted any time I reboot. Googling for a solution I just found this thread. No luck at this moment. :(

Answer (score 4):

This is a known problem with the current Ubuntu images for EC2 built by Canonical:

https:// bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-on-ec2/+bug/371936

You can wait for the next release from Canonical or run the Ubuntu images for EC2 which I publish on http:// alestic.com (and which do not have the same problem).

I have successfully run ejabberd on the Alestic.com images.

Answer (score 2):

I know this a super old thread but one the pops up on ggl,
yes it is cloud-init, on my debian ami I added my custom entries in:

```
/etc/cloud/templates/hosts.debian.tmpl
```

lets see if that works on next auto-reboot by

```
aws ec2 create-ami ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try [CloudInit](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CloudInit) to perform your hosts file cleanup during instance boot. It is included in all the current official Ubuntu EC2 images and allows you to run initialization scripts passed by the `--user-data` switch of `ec2-run-instances` (or the respective input field(s) in the AWS Console wizard) which will be run at boot. Kind of like `rc.local`.

Edit: I did not realize it was Eric himself who wrote the other comment, at first. He's got lots of useful entries in his blog at Alestic, including [one regarding the mentioned UserData](http://alestic.com/2009/06/ec2-user-data-scripts).